# API returns success for OG Post but it doesn't appear on facebook profile

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I'm developing a simple app that has a feature to compose user pictures and post them as a OG Story to facebook.

I followed the Facebook docs and I'm issuing the POST requests (I know I could batch them, I'm just trying to get any version working), I do get an story ID, but I can't find the story on Facebook. (permission set to friends)

I'm posting it with the path /me/:
When I check in the Graph Explorer this path returns an empty { 'data' : [] }
I know the story won't be posted on my profile, but I need to see it somewhere.

I need to test things such as deep linking (I know url is currently set to nil), but I can't find the story! The only place I could manage to see the picture is when I go to 
developer page and click on 'preview'.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Here is the source code:

```
- (void) publishPhoto
{
    // stage an image
    [FBRequestConnection startForUploadStagingResourceWithImage:self.photo.image completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        if(!error) {
            NSLog(@"Successfuly staged image with staged URI: %@", [result objectForKey:@"uri"]);

            // instantiate a Facebook Open Graph object
            NSMutableDictionary<FBOpenGraphObject> *object = [FBGraphObject openGraphObjectForPostWithType:@"<APPNAMESPACE>:picture" title:@"" image:@[@{@"url":[result objectForKey:@"uri"], @"user_generated" : @"true"}] url:nil description:@""];

            // Post custom object
            [FBRequestConnection startForPostOpenGraphObject:object completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                if(!error) {
                    // get the object ID for the Open Graph object that is now stored in the Object API
                    NSString *objectId = [result objectForKey:@"id"];
                    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"object id: %@", objectId]);

                    // create an Open Graph action
                    id<FBOpenGraphAction> action = (id<FBOpenGraphAction>)[FBGraphObject graphObject];
                    [action setObject:objectId forKey:@"picture"];

                    // create action referencing user owned object
                    [FBRequestConnection startForPostWithGraphPath:@"/me/<APPNAMESPACE>:take" graphObject:action completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                        if(!error) {
                            NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"OG story posted, story id: %@", [result objectForKey:@"id"]]);
                            [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"OG story posted"
                                                        message:@"Check your Facebook profile or activity log to see the story."
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK!"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
                        } else {
                            // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
                            // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
                            NSLog(@"Encountered an error posting to Open Graph: %@", error.description);
                        }
                    }];

                } else {
                    // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
                    // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
                    NSLog(@"Encountered an error posting to Open Graph: %@", error.description);
                }
            }];

        } else {
            // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
            // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
            NSLog(@"Error staging an image: %@", error.description);
        }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it with iPhone device instead of simulator. It'll work